# C# Anonymous types cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, anonymous-types

What is wrong with this code-snippet?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new { Name = "A", Price = 3.003 };

        obj.Name = "asdasd";
        obj.Price = 11.00;

        Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}\nPrice = {1}", obj.Name, obj.Price);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Error   5   Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.Name' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only .....\CS_30_features.AnonymousTypes\Program.cs  65  13  CS_30_features.AnonymousTypes
Error   6   Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.Price' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only    .....\CS_30_features.AnonymousTypes\Program.cs  66  13  CS_30_features.AnonymousTypes
```

How to re-set values into an anonymous type object?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Anonymous types in C# are immutable and hence do not have property setter methods.  You'll need to create a new anonmyous type with the values

```
obj = new { Name = "asdasd", Price = 11.00 };
```

Comment: One more thing to note, is that if the new anonymous type has the same number and type of properties in the same order it will be of the same internal type as the first

Comment: This could be a very useful note, thank you for adding that! +1

Answer (score 23):

Anonymous types are created with read-only properties. You can't assign to them after the object construction.

From [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) on MSDN:

> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of read-only properties into a single object without having to first explicitly define a type.

Answer (score 7):

> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of
>   **read-only properties** into a single
>   object without having to first
>   explicitly define a type. The type
>   name is generated by the compiler and
>   is not available at the source code
>   level. The type of the properties is
>   inferred by the compiler. The
>   following example shows an anonymous
>   type being initialized with two
>   properties called Amount and Message.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Use [ExpandoObject](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject/) instead since it supports updating/adding new properties after object creation (it has been around since since C# 4).

Note that it is important to declare the object using the keyword `dynamic` (instead of `var`)

```
using System.Dynamic;

dynamic person = new ExpandoObject();
person.FirstName = "John";
person.LastName = "Doe";
```