# Update only a single item in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Currently I update a single item in a database as follows:

```
 var master = (from tmi in db._Masters where tmi.Id == Id select tmi).FirstOrDefault();
 master.logPosition++;
 db.SubmitChanges();
```

This strikes me as inefficient, as (I think) I am pulling out a full DB row to just update a single value. Is there a more efficient query I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select only the field you want to modify by adjusting your original linq select:

```
var master = (from tmi in db._Masters 
              where tmi.Id == Id 
              select new { tmi.logPosition }).FirstOrDefault(); 
 master.logPosition++; 
 db.SubmitChanges();
```

EDIT: By selecting the specific data into associated properties, the property logPosition should lose its read-only status and be fully updatable.

```
var master = (from tmi in db._Masters 
              where tmi.Id == Id 
              select new { 
                  ID = tmi.ID, 
                  logPosition = tmi.logPosition }).FirstOrDefault(); 
 master.logPosition++; 
 db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: maybe master++ ? if you select new {tmi.logPosition} it will return logPosition not a class that has logPosition as a property.

Comment: But this give a "property cannot be assinged -- it is readonly" error? (I did try it before).

Comment: @Stephan P.: If the query ended `select tmi.logPosition` then you'd be right, but the end of the query creates a new instance of an anonymous type, so Joel is correct.

Comment: @linq - Truthfully I was only focusing on the query itself to reduce it. I'll edit it to put together something closer to a full solution that should work.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is LINQ to SQL; please correct if wrong.

You could make a stored procedure and [pull that stored procedure into your `DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384574.aspx) and then invoke the stored procedure instead of using the above query.

Alternatively, you could hand write an update query and use [`DataContext.ExecuteQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery.aspx) to execute the query.

However, **none of this really matters until you profile and find out whether or not this is truly a bottleneck**. If it is not, I would stick with the simplest that works which is what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

@linq

I can't get the accepted answer by Joel to work.

The select new { } creates an anonymous type which is not updatable (as you stated in your comment, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550797/c-anonymous-types-problem)) and is also not part of the DataContext.

I described a couple of [possible solutions](http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/updating-a-single-column-in-linq-to-sql-summary/)

- Stored Procedure
- View
- ExecuteCommand
- dbml mappings

on my blog.